# Pointer to base class-argument type in friend function

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, friend

I'm writing a C++ program involving polymorphism. I need to overload the operators ***"<<"*** and ***">>"*** as friend functions. 
I have the base class ***base*** and 3 derived classes: ***der1***,***der2***,***der3*** and a pointer to the base class *** *p***. If I declare the functions as

```
istream &operator>>(istream &i,der1 &d1) {...}
istream &operator>>(istream &i,der2 &d2) {...}
istream &operator>>(istream &i,der3 &d3) {...}
```

and call them like

```
base *p;
p=new der1;
cin>>p;
```

the program doesn't compile as there's no function with a ***base*** parameter.
But if I declare it so,it doesn't make any difference if the actual object is of type ***der1***,***der2*** or ***der3***,although I want it to behave differently depending on the type of the object.
All I could think of was to create a virtual function in base and override it the inherited classes. But thus,I'll have to call the functions as

```
*p>>cin
```

which doesn't look so natural.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Well you declare 3 functions to take references and then you call one using a pointer; that will be a different function to begin with. And yes, the C++ run time cannot see whether your base pointer points to a derived -- polymorphism depends on the "calling object", not on the argument objects. if you say `p->f()` the code in *p will know what to call, but in `::f(p)` there is no code which introspects *p and decides which f to call. That decision is made at compile time basd on the static tye of p.

Comment: Have you tried `cin>>(*p)`? You are passing a pointer to an operator expecting a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `operator>>` for base class:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &i, base *b) {
    b->ReadFromIstream(i);
    return i;
}
```

Then you make the `ReadFromIstream` a virtual function, and overload it from the derived classes. This way you have the same syntax `cin >> p`, and they behave differently according to the type of `p`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to make the `operator>>` a member. You can't and still keep `cin` on the left side. Just make it a free function and have it call a member (which can then be virtual):

```
struct base { virtual void read(istream &i); };

istream &operator>>(istream &i,base &b) {b.read(i); return i;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have phantasies about the C++ runtime abilities :-). The C++ run time cannot (or chooses not to) see whether your base pointer argument points to a derived -- polymorphism depends on the "calling object", not on the argument objects. if you say `p->f()` the code in `*p` will know what to call, but in `::f(p)` there is no code which introspects `*p` and decides which `f` to call. That decision is made at compile time based on the static type of `p`.

That said, the workaround is the strategy described by @DarkFalcon. Call virtual methods of the object from the function.